# Is it possible to detect who is speaking with Twilio Video JS SDK?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I'm currently implement video call application, something like Google Hangout using Twilio Video. I want to show the video of person who is speaking at that time in the background.

Is it possible to detect who is speaking with Twilio Video JS SDK ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

The Twilio Video SDKs now include support for [detecting and updating the dominant speaker](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/detecting-dominant-speaker). Please see [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/detecting-dominant-speaker) for full details.

**Original answer**

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is nothing currently built into the SDK that makes that possible. However, you could try [audio analysis using the Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) to determine a moving average of the loudest remote audio track and use that to display the current speaker. This is not something I've tried just yet, but I think it would be interesting to experiment with.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, I managed to get the result I want using `getStats()` method using Twilio Video JS SDK. I'll put the example code here so it could be useful for people who are looking to implement the same functionality.

Reference: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.10.0/docs/Room.html

```
  room.getStats().then(statsReportArray => {
    statsReportArray.forEach(report => {
      let maximumAudioLevel = 0;
      let loudestTrackId = null;

      report.remoteAudioTrackStats.forEach(audioStat => {
        if (audioStat.audioLevel > maximumAudioLevel) {
          maximumAudioLevel = audioStat.audioLevel;
          loudestTrackId = audioStat.trackId;
        }
      });
```